# Facebook test users tag location

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, geolocation

My facebook app is currently in development mode and I'm using facebook test users.  The app rely's on users tagging locations in their posts, however, it seems that test users do not have the capability to do this.  When I try to 'check in' with a test user, no locations appear or can be entered.  How would I go about testing a location based facebook app??

Comment: how would that even be possible, with publish_actions being deprecated?

Comment: I don't understand?  I'm using webhooks for my app and it works fine.  I have an endpoint set up that receives notifications from facebook when users post, I'm just not able to tag/check-in to locations.

Comment: I'm thinking I might just have to mock the data (facebook has examples) and not test it until I make the app live.  Was hoping I wouldn't have to do that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Places are essentially pages, and test users can not interact with real places/pages.

You can either create a page when logged in as a test user, those you should be able to "find" and use for tagging then;

or you test with real users (admin/developer/tester role in the app), as real accounts those can interact with real pages as well.

Comment: Real users webhooks aren't working, only test users.  Also test users can't create a page it seems.  It always asks for a City/State even though that is filled out :(